# how to combine or group conditions in a postgres where clause with or

Tags: postgresql, where-clause

I want to execute a postgres where clause with or. in those query i have common conditions which must be applied to my query. and also there is a conditional logics inside that query which i want to execute. for example

```
select *from [tablename] where (tablename.column1 = 'value1' and tablename.column2 > condition1 and commonconditions ) or (tablename.column1 = 'value2' and tablename.column2 < condition2 and commonconditions
```

in place of commonconditions i have a lengthy condition which apply different conditions for different column. what i want is that instead of repeating each condition inside where and or clause is there a better way

i tried to execute this logic by where clause with  case expressions, like this

```
select *from [my-table-name] where ( CASE 
     WHEN column1 = 0 THEN condition1 
     ELSE condition2
  END
)
```

, but from stack overflow i  have learned that using where clause with or will be the query with better performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you're trying to avoid repeating common conditions in WHERE ... OR ? In that case you can abstract the common conditions like so:

`SELECT
tablename.columns
FROM
tablename
WHERE
(common_condition_1, cc_2, cc_3)
AND
(
(specific_condition_1, sc_2, sc_3) OR
(specific_condition_4, sc_5, sc_6)
)`